# CKFinder PHP- How to store files in different folders created with the name of month

Tags: php, ckfinder3

I want to store files in the folder which name is the month of uploading?
How to make it happen?
I use the CKFinder 3.5.
I found some solution on the web, but they doesn't work on version 3.5.

````
$sServerDir = $this->_currentFolder->getServerPath();

if ($_GET[‘command’] == ‘QuickUpload’){
　$sServerDir .= ‘/’. date(‘Y/m’); 
}

if (!file_exists($sServerDir)){ 
　 CKFinder_Connector_Utils_FileSystem::createDirectoryRecursively($sServerDir);
}```
````

Comment: What is the final value of `$sServerDir`? Does CKFinder Connector Utils provide any error handling or documentation?

Comment: I can't find $sServerDir in version 3.5, may be $sServerDir is in early version.

Comment: I'm referring to the variable you define. Is it set to the path you expect? I assume the directory is not created. Are any errors thrown?